# How to use aggregate function in aggregate function?

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS I have the following code for one of my fields:

```
(DateDiff("n",FIRST(Fields!Date.Value), LAST(Fields!Date.Value, "grp_Order")))
```

I now want to take an AVG of all these fields....How would I go about doing this without getting the nested aggregate error?

Comment: tried using a subquery? -> select avg from (select datediff("n"....))

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question please? [SSRS question on calculating dates from a grouped field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152668/ssrs-question-on-calculating-dates-from-a-grouped-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I remember doing this sort of thing in Crystal Reports....

Can you place the code into a field, then take the avg of that new field?

Field 1 --> code behind : (DateDiff("n",FIRST(Fields!Date.Value), LAST(Fields!Date.Value, "grp_Order")))

Field 2 --> code behind : AVG ( Field 1 ).

I would imagine that Field 2 could only exist @ the end of a group in which field 1 exists.